# How to get sum of probabilities of rolling w dice where one is fair and the other one is unfair?

Tags: python-3.x, math, statistics

I am writing a little program and wanted to ask how I can add the logic of having an unfair dice in the game? Right now, my code produces the sum of probabilities of rolling 2 dices with 6 faces for i times. However, it is treating the dices with a 1/6 probability of rolling a given number. How do I tweak it, so that the unfair dice ONLY shows up in the range of 2-5 but never as 1 or 6? The output should the sum of probs for all numbers in range 2-12 given the fair and unfair dice.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

def main():
    dice = 2
    sides = 6
    rolls = int(input("Enter the number of rolls to simulate: "))
    result = roll(dice, sides, rolls)
    maxH = 0
    for i in range(dice, dice * sides + 1):
        if result[i] / rolls > maxH: maxH = result[i] / rolls
    for i in range(dice, dice * sides + 1):
        print('{:2d}{:10d}{:8.2%} {}'.format(i, result[i], result[i] / rolls, '#' * int(result[i] / rolls / maxH * 40)))


def roll(dice, sides, rolls):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for _ in range(rolls):
        d[sum(random.randint(1, sides) for _ in range(dice))] += 1
    return d

main()
```

**Output**

```
Enter the number of rolls to simulate: 10000
 2       265   2.65% ######
 3       567   5.67% #############
 4       846   8.46% ####################
 5      1166  11.66% ############################
 6      1346  13.46% ################################
 7      1635  16.35% ########################################
 8      1397  13.97% ##################################
 9      1130  11.30% ###########################
10       849   8.49% ####################
11       520   5.20% ############
12       279   2.79% ######
```

Comment: If 2-5 are equal, then probs. are {0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0}

Comment: @stark exactly, but the question is what the sum of probabilities if or rolling each number from 2-12 given this caveat,thanks

Comment: You multiply to get the probability of 2 independent events both happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the logic of which results are possible is currently being controlled by the line

```py
random.randint(1, sides)
```

that's the line to change if you want to roll with different bounds. For example, to get `2-5`, you could generalize the function:

```py
def main():
    dice = 2
    sides = 6
    unfair_min = 2
    unfair_max = 5
    rolls = int(input("Enter the number of rolls to simulate: "))
    result_unfair = roll_biased(dice, sides, rolls, min_roll=unfair_min, max_roll=unfair_max)
    maxH = max(result_unfair.values()) / rolls

    for i in range(dice, dice * sides + 1):
        print('{:2d}{:10d}{:8.2%} {}'.format(i, result_unfair[i], result_unfair[i] / rolls,
                                             '#' * int(result_unfair[i] / rolls / maxH * 40)))


def roll_biased(dice, sides, rolls, min_roll=1, max_roll=None):
    if max_roll is None:
        max_roll = sides
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for _ in range(rolls):
        d[sum(random.randint(min_roll, max_roll) for _ in range(dice))] += 1
    return d
```

Which could print:

```
Enter the number of rolls to simulate: 10000
 2         0   0.00% 
 3         0   0.00% 
 4       632   6.32% ##########
 5      1231  12.31% ###################
 6      1851  18.51% #############################
 7      2480  24.80% ########################################
 8      1873  18.73% ##############################
 9      1296  12.96% ####################
10       637   6.37% ##########
11         0   0.00% 
12         0   0.00%
```

You could also generalize this to arbitrary choices (or arbitrary weights) using `random.choices()` as such:

```py
def roll_from_choices(dice, sides, rolls, allowed_rolls=None):
    if allowed_rolls is None:
        allowed_rolls = list(range(1, sides+1))
    d = defaultdict(int)

    for _ in range(rolls):
        d[sum(random.choices(allowed_rolls, k=dice))] += 1
    return d
```

which you can call as:

```py
result_unfair = roll_from_choices(dice, sides, rolls, allowed_rolls=[2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would *start* with a single function that returns the result of a die<sup>(a)</sup> roll, where the options available can be tailored to exclude the impossible, something like:

```py
import random

def throw_die(options):
    return random.choice(options)
```

Then I would code for the generalised case where you can have *any* number of dice, *each* of varying abilities (to be passed as the options when throwing the die). In your particular case, that would be two dice with the second excluding `1` and `6`<sup>(b)</sup>:

```py
dice = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [   2, 3, 4, 5   ]
]
```

Then allocate enough storage for the results (I've wasted a small amount of space here to ensure code for collecting data is much simpler):

```py
min_res = sum([min(die) for die in dice]) # Smallest possible result,
max_res = sum([max(die) for die in dice]) #   and largest.
count = [0] * (max_res + 1)               # Allocate space + extra.
```

Your data collection is then the relatively simple (I've hard-coded the roll count here rather than use input, but you can put that back in):

```py
rolls = 10000 # rolls = int(input("How many rolls? "))
for _ in range(rolls):
    # Throw each die, sum the results, then increment correct count.

    result = sum([throw_die(die) for die in dice])
    count[result] += 1
```

And the data output can be done as (rounding rather than truncating so that highest count has forty hashes - that's just my CDO<sup>(c)</sup> nature kicking in):

```py
hash_mult = 40 / max(count)
for i in range(min_res, max_res + 1):
    per_unit = count[i] / rolls
    hashes = "#" * int(count[i] * hash_mult + 0.5)
    print(f"{i:2d}{count[i]:10d}{per_unit:8.2%} {hashes}")
```

---

The complete program then becomes:

```py
import random

# Throw a single die.

def throw_die(options):
    return random.choice(options)

# Define all dice here as list of lists.
# No zero/negative number allowed, will
#   probably break code :-)

dice = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [   2, 3, 4, 5   ]
]

# Get smallest/largest possible result.

min_res = sum([min(die) for die in dice])
max_res = sum([max(die) for die in dice])

# Some elements wasted (always zero) to simplify later code.
# Example: throwing three normal dice cannot give 0, 1, or 2.

count = [0] * (max_res + 1)

# Do the rolls and collect results.

rolls = 10000
for _ in range(rolls):
    result = sum([throw_die(die) for die in dice])
    count[result] += 1

# Output all possible results.

hash_mult = 40 / max(count)
for i in range(min_res, max_res + 1):
    per_unit = count[i] / rolls
    hashes = "#" * int(count[i] * hash_mult + 0.5)
    print(f"{i:2d}{count[i]:10d}{per_unit:8.2%} {hashes}")
```

and a few sample runs to see it in action:

```
pax:/mnt/c/Users/Pax/Documents/wsl> python prog.py
 3       418   4.18% #########
 4       851   8.51% ####################
 5      1266  12.66% ##############################
 6      1681  16.81% ########################################
 7      1606  16.06% ######################################
 8      1669  16.69% #######################################
 9      1228  12.28% #############################
10       867   8.67% ####################
11       414   4.14% #########

pax:/mnt/c/Users/Pax/Documents/wsl> python prog.py
 3       450   4.50% ##########
 4       825   8.25% ###################
 5      1206  12.06% ############################
 6      1655  16.55% #######################################
 7      1679  16.79% ########################################
 8      1657  16.57% #######################################
 9      1304  13.04% ###############################
10       826   8.26% ###################
11       398   3.98% #########

pax:/mnt/c/Users/Pax/Documents/wsl> python prog.py
 3       394   3.94% #########
 4       838   8.38% ####################
 5      1271  12.71% ##############################
 6      1617  16.17% ######################################
 7      1656  16.56% #######################################
 8      1669  16.69% ########################################
 9      1255  12.55% ##############################
10       835   8.35% ####################
11       465   4.65% ###########
```

---

*Footnotes:*

*<sup>(a)</sup> Using the correct nomenclature for singular die and multiple dice, in case any non-English speakers are confused.*

*<sup>(b)</sup> You could also handle cases like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]` where you're twice as likely to get a `4` as any other numbers. Anything much more complex than that would probably better be handled with a tuple representing each possible result and its relative likelihood. Probably a little too complex to put in a footnote (given it's not a requirement of the question) but you can always ask about this in a *separate* question if you're interested.*

*<sup>(c)</sup> Just like OCD but in the Correct Damn Order :-)*